# website to debug android apps on actual devices

Tags: android

I have android app already in the market , I tested it on my android and no bugs appeared , now some users are complaining about problems on specific devices ( motorla bionic and samsung galaxy s2) I don't have these devices around and it is inefficient to buy them .
I googled alittle and found :
http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/android.html
and 
http://handsetcloud.com
but I'm looking for something more professional (with catlog) if possible.

Regards,

Comment: It would be good to have such a service, except that if you've had a truly great and unique idea, you've just given the idea away to a third party.